# Hyper-V 2019 Server network drivers

Tags: hyper-v, drivers

What OS driver is used for Hyper-V 2019 server (host) network adapters?
Is it a Windows 2012 Server or Windows 10 driver?

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V 2019 Server drivers are Windows 10 based.

Be sure your PnP device ID is in the

```
[Intel.NTamd64.10.0]
```

section of the *.inf file to make it working under HV'19 Server

Could be ID is stated under

```
[Intel.NTamd64.10.0.1]
```

section. If so, just copy it down to the 10.0 section to enable driver for HV'19 Server.